# How to get Radon Transform pseudocode from the equation

Tags: math, pseudocode, equation

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to convert scary looking maths equations (without being able to understand them) into pseudocode so I can implement it into Java?

If anyone knows of a tool that could help me understand this equation that would be great.

[Radon Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If it's for medical imaging then please, try to understand it before implementing.

Answer (score 3):

If  you can't understand the maths then you shouldn't attempt to implement the function.  Instead you should find an existing implementation, verify and validate it, and use it.

There are just so many ways to come unstuck translating this sort of function from pseudocode into a programming language that anyone who attempts to help you in this misguided proposal is doing you, and by extension your customers, a serious disservice.

The tool for understanding the equation is math{s}.

Answer (score 3):

Ten years ago [numerical receipes](http://www.nr.com/) was the source for programming complex equations... here's a white paper on the radon transformation:

- http://www.nr.com/whp/radonpreprint.pdf

Then, you might look at existing implementations of the equation - for example:

- http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/radon.html
- http://dcssi.istm.cnr.it/Cantele/documenti/Radon.html
- http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_man-2.9.0/library/PET/man/radon.html

Comment: You might have discovered Numerical Recipes ten years ago, but it's been out for 20.  It's a book that takes a great deal of criticism for its implementations, but I always thought the prose describing the approaches was fantastic.